# When will "create or alter" be available to all accounts?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

As discussed in the video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k20yLpW8-xU&t=782s), create or alter enables declarative table definitions and updates.

The video states it is in private preview. How can I get access? When will it be available to all accounts?

Comment: You can ask your account manager for access but you’re more likely to get it granted if you can provide a use case that would help Snowflake to test it. If it’s in private preview then it won’t yet have an official date for going GA  (and probably not one for going into public preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake has a policy of not promising dates. So for any question "when is the ____ feature currently in private preview going into public preview?" - the answer is "we don't know, but hopefully soon".

The best place to monitor to check what comes into public preview is: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/new-features